# Ubuntu 20.04 - Applications take too long to start up

Tags: 20.04, filezilla, wps-office

Some applications like Filezilla, WPS 2019 Office are taking too long to startup in Ubuntu 20.04. Same versions of these applications worked well in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I guess the applications you face this problem are installed as snaps. You can che which sanps are installed with `snap list`.

Comment: Installed both Filezilla and WPS 2019 applications with DEB packages.

Comment: Tur off animations in tweaks.

Comment: Some applications installed as snaps like Kdenlive and Sublime-text launch within 2-5 seconds. Whereas others like Filezilla and WPS 2019 are taking more than 30 seconds to launch even with animations disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I've got some older applications (grsync, MasterPDF Editor (since updated), VueScan (since updated) built on GTK2 that have/had the same behavior on 19.10 and 20.04. Installing the packages:

libcanberra-gtk-module 
appmenu-gtk2-module

solved the problem for me. Reboot after installation.

If they don't help, you can remove the packages in the usual way.

Comment: Solution really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What helped was to remove old manually installed files from `/usr/local/lib`. In particular, the `libimobiledevice` libs were causing issues, since the Gnome apps (via `gvfs`) were using these instead of the system-installed ones.

I identified the issue by running, e.g., `nautilus` in the terminal to see what it was logging to the console and that it had issues with the `gvfs` service.

Also see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1877135